# XSLT: How to parse HTML embedded in XML tags

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I came across situation where XML tag has HTML code that needs to be parsed in XSLT. Here is the XML sample:

```
<note>
    <text>&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is another paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;</text>
</note>
```

I want the embedded paragraph elements to be stored in different variables.

`This is a paragraph.` should be stored in one variable and `This is another paragraph.` should be stored in another variable.

Can you please help?

Comment: You can do it in standard XSLT 3 using `parse-xml-fragment`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CQ for an example. Expecting to do that in plain XSLT 1.0 in a single step is audacious, unless you have an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports an extension or easily allows you to implement one having access to an (X)HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for. I changed the tag from `xslt-1.0` to `xslt-3.0` You can post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Parsing XML documents with `parse-xml` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-xml or XML fragments with `parse-xml-fragment` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-xml-fragment is supported in XSLT 3.0, in earlier versions you would have to rely on processor specific extension provided or implementable.

Your escaped code looks like an XHTML fragment so it should be parseable with `parse-xml-fragment` as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CQ which does

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="text">
      <div>
          <xsl:variable name="contents" select="parse-xml-fragment(.)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="p1" select="$contents/p[1]"/>
          <xsl:variable name="p2" select="$contents/p[2]"/>
          <xsl:sequence select="$p1, $p2"/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```